# Efficient Calculation of Derivatives for PINN Solvers in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, jit

I am currently trying to implement Physics Informed Neural Networks ([PINNs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999118307125)). PINNs involve computing derivatives of model outputs with respect to its inputs. These derivatives are then used to calculate PDE residuals which could be Heat, Burger, Navier-Stokes Equation etc. Therefore, one needs to compute higher order partial derivatives. I tried to use `torch.autograd.grad` to compute those partial derivatives. Here is the function I have implemented:

```
def diff(y, xs):
    grad = y
    ones = torch.ones_like(y)
    for x in xs:
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(grad, x, grad_outputs=ones, create_graph=True)[0]
    return grad
```

`diff(y, xs)` simply computes `y`'s derivative with respect to every element in `xs`. This way denoting and computing partial derivatives is much easier:

```
y_pred = model([t, x, y])
diff(y_pred, [x, x]) # dydxx
diff(y_pred, [x, y, t]) # dydxyt
```

This function allows me to write PDEs in a much compact and easier way, as an example here is the Heat Equation in 1D:

```
u = model([x, t])
def heat(u, x, t):
    alpha = 1.0
    return diff(u, [x, x]) - alpha * diff(u, [t])
```

One of the limitations of PINNs other than data is the training time. To reduce the training time I tried using `torch.jit.script`, `torch.jit.trace` and `torch.compile`.

- JIT Script implementation of the `diff(y, xs)`:

  ```
  @torch.jit.script
  def D(y: torch.Tensor, xs: List[torch.Tensor]) -> torch.Tensor:
      func: torch.Tensor = y
      ones: List[Optional[torch.Tensor]] = [torch.ones_like(y)]
      for x in xs:
          grad = torch.autograd.grad(
              [func],
              [x],
              grad_outputs=ones,
              allow_unused=True,
              create_graph=True)[0]
          func = grad if grad is not None else torch.zeros_like(x)
      return func
  ```
- I then tried to implement the heat equation as well but was stuck with an error:

  - JIT Trace:

    ```
    N = 1000
    x = torch.linspace(0.0, 1.0, N, requires_grad=True, device=device).reshape((N,1))
    t = torch.linspace(0.0, 1.0, N, requires_grad=True, device=device).reshape((N,1))
    u = torch.sin(x * np.pi) * torch.exp(-t**2) # A typical solution to the Heat Eqn.

    def heat(u, x, t):
       alpha = 1.0
       res = D(u, [x, x]) - alpha * D(u, [t]) # Uses jit.script diff
       return res

    traced_heat = torch.jit.trace(heat, (u, x, t))
    ```

    The error:

    ```
    Runtime  Error: The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
    Traceback of TorchScript (most recent call last):
       File "/tmp/ipykernel_19890/2258731968.py", line 6, in D
         ones: List[Optional[torch.Tensor]] = [torch.ones_like(y)]
         for x in xs:
             grad = torch.autograd.grad(
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
                 [func],
                 [x],
    RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
    ```

I have no idea of what is causing this, I have no experiment with PyTorch but wanted to export what I have written (in Tensorflow) during [my studies](https://github.com/SalihTasdelen/pinn-examples) since PyTorch provides more flexibility and control. However, with this much flexibility I have no idea which option should I be using. Should I try `TorchDynamo` instead?

- If I run `torch._dynamo.explain` on `heat` function I get the following explanation:

  ```
  Dynamo produced 1 graphs with 0 graph break and 2 ops
  Break reasons: 

  TorchDynamo compilation metrics:
  Function, Runtimes (s)
  _compile, 0.0880, 0.0152, 0.0046
  OutputGraph.call_user_compiler, 0.0000
  ```
- Then, if I try to compile the `heat` function, I get the following error:

  ```
  compheat = torch.compile(heat, backend='inductor', fullgraph=True)
  r = compheat(u, x, t)
  ```

  Error:

  ```
  Unsupported: inlining disallowed: <function grad at 0x7f36642888b0>

  from user code:
     File "/tmp/ipykernel_19890/543225163.py", line 3, in cheat
      res = D(u, [x, x]) - alpha * D(u, [t])
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_19890/2258731968.py", line 6, in D
      grad = torch.autograd.grad(


  You can suppress this exception and fall back to eager by setting:
      torch._dynamo.config.suppress_errors = True
  ```

I am open to both suggestions on design and solutions for the errors that I have. I am new to PyTorch and have limited experience with the framework, but I am eager to learn and apply its capabilities to solve complex problems like PDEs using PINNs. I apologize in advance if any of the information I have provided is incorrect or incomplete due to my limited experience with PyTorch. I am here to learn and would appreciate any corrections or feedback from the community. Thank you for your understanding.

Please note that as a toy example I have used the following NN, which first takes the inputs as a list, and stacks them before feeding it to the actual layers:

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_input):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_sigmoid_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(n_input, 32),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(32, 32),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(32, 1)
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.hstack(x)
        return self.linear_sigmoid_stack(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple, in order for `torch.autograd` to keep track of the gradients, the `torch.nn.Module.forward` must accept NN inputs as separate arguments. This way the backward graph is generated and the gradients of the outputs can be computed using both `torch.autograd` or `torch.func.grad`.

However, please note that `torch.func.grad` requires model parameters to be inputs to the model as well since training will require gradients w.r.t. the parameters as well. To use `torch.func.grad` to compute gradients of the `Heat` model in the question one would,

```
from functools import wraps
from torch import func
from torch import _dynamo as dynamo
model = Heat()

def make_sum(f):
    # Make functional summation
    @wraps(f)
    def _sum(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs).sum()

    return _sum

def fgrad(f, argnum=1):
    # Make functional gradient
    return func.grad(make_sum(f), argnums=argnum)

u = dynamo.allow_in_graph(model)
u_t = fgrad(u, argnum=1)
u_xx = fgrad(u_x, argnum=2)

def pde_residual(params, t, x):
    # Heat Equation gradient
    return u_t(params, t, x) - 0.05*u_xx(params, t, x)
```

The `pde_residual` can be compiled using `torch.compile`. To benchmark the compiled training I have also implemented the `torch.autograd` version,

```
from torch import autograd

def grad(u, xs, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True):
    return autograd.grad(u.sum(),
                         xs,
                         create_graph=create_graph,
                         retain_graph=retain_graph)

def pde_residual(u_pred, t, x):
    u_t, u_x = func.grad(u_pred, [t, x])
    u_xx = func.grad(u_x, x)[0]
    return u_t - 0.05*u_xx
```

Interestingly, there were no speedups and in fact `torch.autograd` performed way faster than the compiled version.

So, I switched to dynamic graphs instead of compiling and implemented a Python package for PINNs called [remin](https://github.com/SalihTasdelen/remin). Below is the capabilities of my framework.

**remin** is a Python module that provides a framework for developing Physics Informed Neural Networks (PINNs) using PyTorch. This module integrates PyTorch for model creation and training, Latin-Hypercube sampling for geometry creation, and also includes a small, user-friendly module for creating geometries.

If you want to contribute to **remin**, feel free to submit a pull request or open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/SalihTasdelen/remin).